# Median of truncated / limited normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, median

The peoples weight is normally distributed $\mathcal{N}(0,\,1)$

The $\mu \; , \; \sigma \; and \; \sigma^2$ are known.

How can i calculate the median weight of people if everyone who weights less than amount of x is removed / ignored.

I would appreciate some hints on what would be the best way to begin to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ denote the CDF of the uncensored weight, then the median $m_x$ of the weight censored below the value $x$ solves $F(m_x)=\frac12(1+F(x))$.